# How to add a column that shows the total number of rows in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this table and I wish to add a column that gives the total number of rows in the table:

Table now:

```
Name         PAT_ID        
---------------------
Brian          123
Brian          356
Brian          3546
Brian          987
```

Desired output:

```
Name         PAT_ID       TOTAL     
------------------------------------
Brian          123          4
Brian          356          4
Brian          3546         4
Brian          987          4
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) clause, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT (
  Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PAT_ID INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PATIENT (Name, PAT_ID)
VALUES ('Brian', 123), ('Brian', 356), ('Brian', 3546), ('Brian', 987);

SELECT *
     ,COUNT(*) OVER () AS [total]
FROM PATIENT
```

In the OVER clause, you can use PARTITION BY which is like GROUP BY. For example, you can count the rows only for particular user:

```
SELECT *
     ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS [total]
FROM PATIENT
```